# What is the longest range non-ult ability belonging to an AP mid?

Tags: league-of-legends

I believe it is Xerath's Arcanopulse(`Q`), even without the Locus of Power(`W`) buff. Is this correct?

Comment: Note: Rather than just answering the question with a guess, please back up your answer with evidence, such as screenshot comparisons from within the game or stats about ranges of different long-range non-ult abilities.

Answer (score 13):

The following ability's have been mentioned by other people but non of them have had a source or numbers to compare.

- **Heimerdinger's Hextech Micro-Rockets**(`W`) has a **1000** range, his **CH-1 Concussion Grenade**(`E`) can technically reach longer with a 925 range and estimated 250 raius reaching **1175** - [source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Heimerdinger_the_Revered_Inventor#Hextech_Micro-Rockets)
- **Xerath's Arcanopulse**(`Q`) has a 900 range and when combined with his **Locus of Power**(`W`) is increased to **1300** - [source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Xerath#Arcanopulse)
- **Twisted Fate's Wild Cards**(`Q`) has a **1450** range - [source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Twisted_Fate_the_Card_Master#Wild_Cards)
- **Nidalee's Javelin Toss**(`Q`) has a **1500** range - [source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nidalee_the_Bestial_Huntress#Javelin_Toss)
- **Ziggs' Bouncing Bomb**(`Q`) can reach up to an estimated 1400 range and with a 150 estimated radius can hit targets up to **1550** - [source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ziggs_the_Hexplosives_Expert#Bouncing_Bomb)

You could play Janna or Maokai as AP Mid and they would beat them all with:

- **Janna's Howling Gale**(`Q`) has up to **1700** range - [source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Janna_the_Storm%27s_Fury#Howling_Gale)
- **Maokai's Sapling Toss**(`E`) reaching 1100 range, then another estimated 500 aggro range radius and then at end another estimated 350 explosion radius ending up with an impressive, though highly unlikely, estimated range of **1950** - [source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Maokai#Sapling_Toss)

Answer (score -1):

Ashe is commonly played as a mid in public games, at least, though typically not as an AP. Her Hawkshot has a travel range of 2,500 / 3,250 / 4,000 / 4,750 / 5,500.